# Is it possible to open embedded HTML file using Xamarin.Essetianls.Browser

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Need to present fairly large T&Cs embedded document in Xamarin Native (NOT Xamarin.Forms). Xamarin.Essetianls.Broswser.OpenAsync("url") works brilliantly for the website page, but getting error:

```
The specified URL has an unsupported scheme. Only HTTP and HTTPS URLs are supported.
```

if trying

```
await Browser.OpenAsync("file://Data/TsAndCs.html")
```

Comment: you can use a WebView control in your app to display local html

Answer (score 0):

In android, you can put the your local html page to the Assets folder, please notice the Build Action to the `AndroidAsset`.

[image]

Then you can create a interface to get the html file path.

```
public interface IBaseUrl
{
     string Get();
}
```

Achieve it in the Android folder.

```
    [assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl_Android))]
namespace MyWebView.Droid
{
    public class BaseUrl_Android : IBaseUrl
    {
        public BaseUrl_Android()
        {
        }

        public string Get()
        {
            return "file:///android_asset/";
        }
    }
}
```

For IOS achievement, you can refer to this thread:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#local-html-content

Notice: If you want to Interaction between JS code and control of xamarin forms before html page displayed, please put this part code to `Navigated="MywebView_Navigated"`

Here is my local html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <span id="myfont">This is Local Html</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
function factorial(num) {
        if (num === 0 || num === 1)
            return 1;
        for (var i = num - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            num *= i;
        }
        return num;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

Comment: @Algis Are there any update for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue